# How does one align a pointer that is allocated on the heap (using malloc)?

Tags: c, pointers

This causes a seg fault when I try to align the pointer returned by calloc to BY2PAGE. Is there a way (or is it even legal) to modify the pointer such that it is aligned after the allocation?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BY2PG 0x1000
char * vm;


static int roundup(u_int n, int align) {
    if(n % align == 0) ; 
    // is already aligned so
    // no action required, else
    // align it:
    else n += (align - (n % align));
    
    return n;
}

int main() {

    vm = (char *) calloc(0x100000, sizeof(char));

    vm = (char *) roundup((u_int)vm, BY2PG);

    vm[0] = 5; // seg fault
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than risk implementation and undefined behavior with brittle user code, to align an allocation, use:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // Since C11
void *aligned_alloc(size_t alignment, size_t size);
```

> The `aligned_alloc` function allocates space for an object whose alignment is specified by alignment, whose size is specified by size, ...

---

OP is assuming 1) `(u_int)vm` does not lose vital information (I think this is the seg fault source) 2) that the adjusted integer, cast to an `int`, converted back to a pointer is valid 3) `calloc(large_value, 1)` returned non-`NULL` [@Lindydancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69977548/how-does-one-align-a-pointer-that-is-allocated-on-the-heap-using-malloc/69977730#comment123700405_69977548)
.

Even the initial allocation is suspect as `calloc(0x100000, sizeof(char));` it is unclear how many `0x1000` sized blocks are available to use after the questionable `roundup()`.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to @WeatherVane - this version works as I expected

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BY2PG 0x1000
char * vm;


static uintptr_t roundup(uintptr_t n, int align) {
    if(n % align == 0) ; 
    // is already aligned so
    // no action required, else
    // align it:
    else n += (align - (n % align));
    
    return n;
}

int main() {

    vm = (char *) calloc(0x100000, sizeof(char));

    printf("%08x\n", vm);

    vm = (char *) roundup((uintptr_t)vm, BY2PG);

    printf("%08x\n", vm);

    vm[0] = 5;

    printf("%d\n", vm[0]);
}
```

Comment: This relies on undefined behaviour (since you intend to use it for things other than `char*` given your use if ``intptr_t` instead of `char*`). You also end up with less memory than needed. (You would need to over-allocate by `BY2PG-1` to avoid this problem.) For each and both of these reasons, the other answer is better.